# Why do bands arise from a lattice of two-site "atoms"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electronic-band-theory

What is the basic reason why an “atom” with a trapping potential with two bound states becomes a system with two bands when a large number of such atoms are assembled into a lattice?

Answer (score 1):

If you couple a large number N of identical atoms with two energy levels so that they can interact, the energy levels will split up into a closely spaced energy level band with N levels each. This is analogous to the classical case of two coupled identical oscillators where the oscillation frequencies split into two frequencies near the oscillation frequency of the uncoupled oscillators. N coupled oscillators would have N closely spaced oscillation frequencies.

Comment: *"If you couple a large number N of identical atoms with two energy levels so that they can interact, the energy levels will split up into a closely spaced energy level band with N levels each."* Isn't that begging the question?

Comment: @ DanielSank - Not really. The answer states that the coupling of atoms with identical energy levels leads to a splitting of each of these levels into N closely spaced energy levels forming an energy band. Of course, this is the statement of a fact without working out a rather lengthy theory exposition. The analogy to the frequency splitting in two coupled classical oscillators should, however, be helpful. So the OP gets an idea how the energy bands form and how many discrete energy levels they contain as opposed to continuous energy bands.